# Have a hidden property on a getter that returns a string

Tags: javascript

In ES6 is it possible to have a getter return a string, but return a property if requested?

An example:

```
myForm.title
// 'The foo of the bar, was there.'

myForm.title.valid
// true
```

I think I remember seeing something along the lines of this somewhere, kind of how jQuery's `$` is a function, but you can call methods on it.

Comment: nope ..... a property can't be both a string and an object

Comment: @adeneo Even if it's a getter? A getter isn't technically a static property.

Comment: A getter could return either, depending on a condition, unfortunately defining something like `get title () {}` you'd have no idea wether or not it was called "alone" or with a chained on `.valid` property, so there's no way to determine what to return.

Comment: @adeneo Well, maybe something like that could be in ES7? That would be really cool.

Comment: Here's an example -> https://jsfiddle.net/0wmfrub9/

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object with a `toString` method.

```js
var myForm = {
        title: {
            valid: true,
            toString: function () { return 'The foo of the bar, was there.'; }
        }
    };

console.log(myForm.title + ''); // workaround to force to use toString
console.log(myForm.title.valid)
```

Comment: It's a neat trick, but then you could just as well use `form.title.string` and have a property with that string, and avoid the whole schebackle

Comment: usually, the forcing to string is not necessary, but the `console.log` methot here at stack snippets.

Comment: I guess it depends on the use case, if you insert it somewhere you'd otherwise get `[Object, object]` it would of course work as expected